# How can I Copy the value of textbox to my query In PHP

Tags: php, mysql

[I have my textbox named Title here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpd3U.png)

The Title is the upper most Textbox!
I have a query where i should copy the value of that textbox which is 'A' to my query here

```
        $sql_query="SELECT * FROM tblpost WHERE Page = 'A' ";
```

this is exactly my code! Hope everyone can guide me because I am Actually new in PHP this is my whole code

```
        <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
      <label>Page Title</label>
      <input name="title" type="text"  value="<?php echo $fetched_row['Title']; ?>" required class="form-control" placeholder="Page Title">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" name="active"  id="active">
          <option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>
          <option value="Actived">Activated</option>
          <option value="Deactivated">Deactivated</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Meta Tags</label>
      <input type="text"  value="<?php echo $fetched_row['Tags']; ?>" name="tags" required class="form-control" placeholder="Add Some Tags...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Category</label>
      <input type="text" name="description"  value="<?php echo $fetched_row['Description']; ?>" class="form-control" required placeholder="Add Category...">
    </div>

         <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Page Title</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Date Created</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>

                         <?php



                        $sql_query="SELECT * FROM tblpost WHERE Page = //I think it's right here ";

                        $result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result_set))
                        {
                          ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row[6]; ?></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:edt_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')">Edit</a>   <a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:delete_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')">Delete</a></td>      
                          </tr>
                            <?php
                     }
                     ?>

                          <script>
                          function myFunction() {
                            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
                            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                              td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                              if (td) {
                                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                                  tr[i].style.display = "";
                                } else {
                                  tr[i].style.display = "none";
                                }
                              }       
                            }
                          }
                          </script>


             </table>

           <center> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update"><strong>UPDATE</strong></button> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn-cancel"><strong>Cancel</strong></button></center>

                 </form>
```

Comment: u want to copy textbox value to query.rite?

Comment: @user3386779 Yes You are exactly right! I' am having problems since yesterday

Comment: I think you need to go back and read up on PHP more. PHP is  server side language and can't act on data that the user types in to the webpage UNTIL the user submits that form or if some javascript communicates data back to the server.
Have a look at this example https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code snippet correctly, at page load time the "title" is carries in a array variable: $fetched_row['Title']

So essentially your code should be something like:

$sql_query="SELECT * FROM tblpost WHERE Page = '".mysql_real_escape_string($fetched_row['Title'])."';";

If this is new code, you really should use mysqli instead of the deprecated mysql, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should first check, if the form was sent and then just use the `$_POST` variable in your sql query, by doing something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-update'])) {
    $sql_query="SELECT * FROM tblpost WHERE Page = '".$_POST['title']."'";
    // ... more code
}
```

This, however, is a really unsafe approach and you shouldn't use the standard `mysql_` functions and instead have a look at for example `mysqli` and `prepared statements`

Comment: The codes doesnt return any value sir. Can you Guide me with the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

In php include connection code and get the input box value

```
<?php
   include("connection.php");  //INCLUDE CONNECTION STRING
   $textbox1=$_REQUEST['title'];   // It's for both post/get methods
   if (isset($_REQUEST['btn-update'])) {  //check the button click by button name
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tblpost WHERE Page = '.$textbox1'";  
   } 
?>
```

Suggestion:Change the name of the button

Comment: can you guide me on where can I place your code sir? Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

Use the name attribute to get the value of the textbox like this:

```
$textTitle = $_POST['title'];
```

`$textTitle` is a variable that returns the value of the textbox.

We use `$_POST[]` variable because you are using post method in your form.

`title` is the name attribute of the input type text.